# Implementing inputted operator in between two numbers

Tags: python, operators, formula, trigonometry, turtle-graphics

I have been messing around lately with imported turtle and trigonometric functions:

```
turtle.goto((x/math.pi)*wavelength,(ypos/10)+math.sin(x)*amplitude)
```

(This is just a snippet of my code, and the x position is irrelevant.)  The

> (ypos/10)+math.sin(x)*amplitude

can easily be re-shaped into the standard formula of:

> y = b + mx (*z for amplitude)

What I want to know is, how could I input an operator into a variable and replace the addition or multiplication with a different symbol?  I have tried everything I can come up with.

Edit: Are these operators any specific data type? I can't find anything about that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could i input an operator into a variable and replace the addition
>   or multiplication with a different symbol?

I recommend you explore Python's operator.py module.  Here's a simple example that just shows the four basic calculator operations:

```
import operator
from random import randint

operations = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}

a, b = randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)

while True:

    operation = input("Enter an operation (+, -, * , / or 'quit') ")

    if operation in operations:

        c = operations[operation](a, b)

        print("{} {} {} = {}".format(a, operation, b, c))
    elif operation == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print("try again")
```

What you shouldn't do is consider `eval`.  You shouldn't open up your code to just anything, but rather some reasonable and safe predefined set of operations.

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Enter an operation (+, -, * or /) +
25 + 97 = 122
Enter an operation (+, -, * or /) -
25 - 97 = -72
Enter an operation (+, -, * or /) *
25 * 97 = 2425
Enter an operation (+, -, * or /) /
25 / 97 = 0.25773195876288657
Enter an operation (+, -, * or /) quit
>
```